# Can I set a taskbar progress state on a dialog box rather than my main form?

Tags: vb.net, taskbar

In my VB.Net application, I've got the following code which allows me to use the app's taskbar icon as a progress bar.

```
Public Sub setTaskbarProgress(ByVal upTo As Integer, ByVal outOfTotal As Integer, ByVal stateType As TaskbarProgressBarState)
If TaskbarManager.IsPlatformSupported Then
        If stateType = Nothing Then stateType = TaskbarProgressBarState.Normal
        Dim tbm As TaskbarManager = TaskbarManager.Instance
        tbm.SetProgressValue(upTo, outOfTotal)
        If upTo = 0 And outOfTotal = 100 Then
            tbm.SetProgressState(TaskbarProgressBarState.NoProgress)
        Else
            tbm.SetProgressState(stateType)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I want to expand that function, ideally so it had a fourth parameter, e.g.

```
Public Sub setTaskbarProgress(ByVal upTo As Integer,
ByVal outOfTotal As Integer, ByVal stateType As TaskbarProgressBarState, _
ByRef target As Form)
```

so that the progress bar (Taskbar.SetProgressValue and TaskBar.SetProgressState) were applied to a specific sub-form or dialogue box in my project, rather than always being applied to the main form.

Is there a way I can specify which window "TaskbarManager" is actually going to apply to? I can't see how I would feed it a 'target'? Does Windows allow this? Any points would be welcome.

Comment: As long as the dialog has a handle (it does) and taskbar presence (probably does, but doesn't _have_ to), I don't think Windows cares.

Comment: Thanks, that's good news. The dialogue box has the property ShowInTaskbar=True and it does have its own taskbar presence. But how do I feed the handle of the relevant dialogue box to the TaskbarManager? I am missing something.

Comment: Are you using the WindowsAPICodePack?

Comment: Apologies for the very tardy response, something manic came up. Yes, I'm using the Microsoft-standard WindowsAPICodePack. @RoyalPotato

Comment: "yourDialogBox.Handle" should be the handle of the box. As inherited from "Control.Handle". https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.handle(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your response @RoyalPotato and apologies again for the incredibly slow reply. I'm still missing one vital and possibly obvious bit of information though, and that is: in my example code in the initial question, how do I pass the window handle to the TaskBarManager so that it knows which window to operate on? It just defaults to the main form and I can't see how to change it.

Comment: Ah, so sorry I didn't understand. If I recall there is an overload to SetProgressValue that takes an intptr (i.e., the window handle).

Comment: Like so: Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Taskbar.TaskbarManager.Instance.SetProgressValue(50, 100, window.Handle)

Answer (score 0):

Well, In any case, yes, you can do it, but the code that you've provided lacks of necessary details of who and how wrapped it to know its behavior, because is not the same if you have full access to the source code to perform any required modification or not, It's not clear whether it is a VB.NET translation of the official `WindowsAPICodePack` C# code, or a custom wrapper by other person.

Anyways, the code you can have, particullary the `TaskbarManager.Instance` member should implement one of the **[ITaskbarList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774652(v=vs.85).aspx)** interfaces, probablly **[ITaskbarList4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562040(v=vs.85).aspx)** (all), and this means you should be able to rework the wrapper to call the **[ITaskbarList::SetProgressValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391698(v=vs.85).aspx)** method passing the target window handle of your dialog.

If for some reason you could need the `ITaskbarList` definition, I translated it time ago to VB.NET (ignoring some methods named as "Fake" that I don't wanted to use)

```
    ''' <remarks>
    ''' <see href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562040(v=vs.85).aspx"/>
    ''' </remarks>
    <ComImport>
    <InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)>
    <Guid("C43DC798-95D1-4BEA-9030-BB99E2983A1A")>
    Public Interface ITaskbarList4

#Region " ITaskbarList "

        <PreserveSig>
        Sub HrInit()

        <PreserveSig>
        Sub AddTab(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr)

        <PreserveSig>
        Sub DeleteTab(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr)

        <PreserveSig>
        Sub ActivateTab(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr)

        <PreserveSig>
        Sub SetActiveAlt(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr)

#End Region

#Region " ITaskbarList2 "

        <PreserveSig>
        Sub MarkFullscreenWindow(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> ByVal fFullscreen As Boolean)

#End Region

#Region " ITaskbarList3 "

        <PreserveSig>
        Sub SetProgressValue(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal ullCompleted As UInt64, ByVal ullTotal As UInt64)

        <PreserveSig>
        Sub SetProgressState(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal tbpFlags As TaskbarProgressBarState)

        <PreserveSig>
        Sub RegisterTab(ByVal hwndTab As IntPtr, ByVal hwndMdi As IntPtr)

        <PreserveSig>
        Sub UnregisterTab(ByVal hwndTab As IntPtr)

        <PreserveSig>
        Sub SetTabOrder(ByVal hwndTab As IntPtr, ByVal hwndInsertBefore As IntPtr)

        <PreserveSig>
        Sub SetTabActive(ByVal hwndTab As IntPtr, ByVal hwndInsertBefore As IntPtr, ByVal dwReserved As UInteger)

        <PreserveSig>
        Function Fake1() As HResult
        ' Function ThumbBarAddButtons(byval hwnd As IntPtr, byval cButtons As UInteger, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)> byval pButtons As ThumbButton()) As HResult

        <PreserveSig>
        Function Fake2() As HResult
        ' Function ThumbBarUpdateButtons(byval hwnd As IntPtr, byval cButtons As UInteger, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)> byval pButtons As ThumbButton()) As HResult

        <PreserveSig>
        Sub Fake3()
        ' Sub ThumbBarSetImageList(byval hwnd As IntPtr, byval himl As IntPtr)

        <PreserveSig>
        Sub SetOverlayIcon(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal hIcon As IntPtr, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal pszDescription As String)

        <PreserveSig>
        Sub SetThumbnailTooltip(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal pszTip As String)

        <PreserveSig>
        Sub SetThumbnailClip(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal prcClip As IntPtr)

#End Region

#Region " ITaskbarList4 "

        Sub Fake4()
        ' Sub SetTabProperties(byval hwndTab As IntPtr, byval stpFlags As SetTabPropertiesOption)

#End Region

    End Interface
```

Additionaly this enumeration:

```
''' <remarks>
''' <see href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391697%28v=vs.85%29.aspx"/>
''' </remarks>
Public Enum TaskbarProgressBarState
    NoProgress = 0
    Indeterminate = &H1
    Normal = &H2
    [Error] = &H4
    Paused = &H8
End Enum
```

Comment: "It's not clear whether it is a VB.NET translation of the official WindowsAPICodePack C# code" or he's using the codepack in binary form. Referencing the .dll.

Comment: I'm just referencing the DLL, I haven't gone 'under the hood' or used a third-party wrapper. If I remember rightly, I just downloaded the pack from here: [link]https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAPICodePack-Core[/link] @ElektroStudios